# how to change the baseurl in yum .repo?

Tags: yum

I am new to yum but I did RTFM and grepped all the available information and I still don't understand something basic.

I have some `foobar.repo` file that yum uses that looks like this:

```
[foobar]
name=foobar
baseurl=http://server/RPMS
enabled=1
```

This works - I can do

> yum update foobar

and it updates.

But now I `mv` the directory `RPMS` to `RPMS1` and I make the corresponding change in the `foobar.repo` file.

Now surprisingly, update does not work anymore, it says that the file

```
http://server/RPMS1/repodata/repomd.xml
```

is not found.  That is not the case, the file is there in the new directory`RPMS1` on the same server which is accessible just like before.

I also tried to

```
yum clean all
yum update foobar
```

still the same problem

What is going on here??

Thank you

Comment: It is always better to re-create the repo metadata to avoid references to old directory. Use `createrepo` util to do that. Take note of `httpd` configuration as well and update accordingly.

Comment: @alvits OK yes I will.  But, you know, the first error message I am getting, specifically points to that file not being there.  That's why I am baffled.

Comment: @alvits I did createrepo, no change, same problem.  How do you do the httpd configuration?

Comment: Have you tested using a browser if it can fetch the `repomd.xml` and all the files within `/repodata/`? If the bowser can't fetch it then you just need to update the `httpd` conf or check if the permission is preserved on the files.

Comment: The `httpd` configuration is dependent on the web server you are using and the operating system. On RHEL like system, it will be in `/etc/httpd/`. Check all the files in that directory that end in `.conf`. Only you would know which file to modify. Alternatively, you can place your `RPMS1` directory under the `documentroot` directory.

Comment: @alvits Yes I verified that both files are accessible from a web browser.

Comment: @alvits I also checked the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file and it did not have anything to do with any RPMS directories

Comment: @alvits sorry this was ID10T error code, I was told the server is different than it really is

Answer (score 0):

sorry this was ID10T error code, I was told the server is different than it really is